# TypeOrm update Entity not updating related one

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have this entity:

```
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  activated: boolean;

  @OneToOne(() => UserAnag, (userAnag) => userAnag.user)
  useranag: UserAnag;
}
```

and this related entity

```
@Entity()
export class UserAnag {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  name: string;
  @Column()
  surname: string;

   @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.useranag, {
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;
```

and this is my update function:

```
async update(id: number, attrs: Partial<UpdateUserDto>) {
    const user = await this.findById(id);
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
    }
    if (attrs.useranag) {
      const useranag = Object.assign(user.useranag, attrs.useranag);
      Object.assign(user, attrs);
      user.useranag = useranag;
    } else {
      Object.assign(user, attrs);
    }
    return this.repo.save(user);
  }
```

my findById function

```
    if (!id) {
      return null;
    }
    const user = await this.repo.find({
      where: { id: id },
      relations: { useranag: true },
    });
    return user[0];
  }
```

If i debug this, i can see that the **userEntity** is correctly updated and also the return have the correct object updated but on database, only **User** entity is correctly **updated**, not Useranag entity.
I try alo setting eager on Useranag but have the same problem. Database is updated only in User not in Useranag

Additional info:
I'm logging the query and before update , select only id and userId on useranag entity that are obviously equal to the original and no update query was launched

Answer (score 2):

The cascade syntax is different. You can either set it as `cascade: true`
or a list of operations to cascade

```js
 @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.useranag, {cascade: true})
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;
```

```js
 @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.useranag, {cascade: ['update', 'delete']})
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;
```

Source: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/relations#cascades

Comment: i have tried this solution at first time but it doesn't work. The User entity will be updated regularly but the other doesn't change. The strange thing is that the response of repo.save() function is correct. Only database doesn't change.

Comment: Your solution is good but not exact. The cascade must be set on other entity. Thank you for suggestion that put me on the right way

Comment: Oh, that's right, I didnt verify the direction of the relationship. Im glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.  I made confusion between onUpdate e cascade: ['update']

The correct way that i find to update my related entity is to set
`cascade: ['update']` in the entity i will update, not in the related entity.

So the correct code is:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  activated: boolean;

  @OneToOne(() => UserAnag, (userAnag) => userAnag.user, {
    cascade: ['update'],
  })
  useranag: UserAnag;
}
```

and

```
@Entity()
export class UserAnag {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  name: string;
  @Column()
  surname: string;
  @Column()
  psn: string;
  @Column()
  discord: string;
  @Column()
  drivernumber: number;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.useranag, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;
}
```